# interpreting the map obtained from a difference of spheres as a homology class

Tags: algebraic-topology

This should be an easy and foundational question, but for some reason I lack clarity on this isssue. The siutation is as follows: Suppose I have a disk $D$, a space $X$, a map $f:D \to X$, and the associated homology class (e.g cellular) $\alpha_D$. Suppose I have a sub-disk $D'$, a map $f': D' \to X$, and the associated homology class $\alpha_{D'}$. Now, I want to interpret $f \restriction_{D - D'}$ as a homology class, and I want to interpret it as the class $\alpha_D - \alpha_{D'}$. Can I do this? (And in what sense)

Comment: If you mean $D'\subset D$, then $D-D'$ isn't even a disk. I could be misinterpreting your notation.

Comment: Yes, @jben2021, $D - D'$ is not a disk, but I still want to interpret the restriction as an element of the homology group.

Answer (score 0):

I appear to have an answer to my own question.

Write $D - D'$ as the union of two disks. Call the homology classes associated with them as $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$. Then, we have that $\alpha_{D'} + \beta_1 + \beta_2$ is the homology class $\alpha_D$, and thus, $\alpha_{D} - \alpha_{D'} = \beta_1 + \beta_2 = \alpha_{D-D'}$. We may therefore interpret $f \restriction_{D - D'}$ as the homology class $\alpha_{D} - \alpha_{D'}$.